# Check on whether a person is subscribed to another person

Tags: postgresql

I have a table of subscribers. It has a connection to the user table.

```
 id | user_id | follower_id |
-----------------------------
 1  |   46    |     71      |
 2  |   46    |     53      |
 3  |   46    |     67      |
 4  |   46    |     34      |
 5  |   89    |     71      |
 6  |   50    |     32      |
 7  |   89    |     53      |
 8  |   12    |     34      |
```

I am user with id 89. I display all subscribers of the user with ID 46

```
SELECT F.USER_ID, F.FOLLOWER_ID, U.USERNAME, U.NAME, U.LAST_LOGIN, (U.USER_ID IS NOT NULL) AS IS_FOLLOWER
FROM FOLLOWERS AS F
INNER JOIN USERS AS U ON (U.USER_ID = F.USER_ID)
WHERE F.USER_ID = '46'
```

I get the result

```
 id | user_id | follower_id | if_follower |
-------------------------------------------
 1  |   46    |     71      |    true     |
 2  |   46    |     53      |    true     |
 3  |   46    |     67      |    true     |
 4  |   46    |     34      |    true     |
```

My problem is how do I check that I am subscribed to users with indexes 52, 53, 67, 89?
What am I waiting for as a result

```
 id | user_id | follower_id | if_follower |
-------------------------------------------
 1  |   46    |     71      |    true     |
 2  |   46    |     53      |    true     |
 3  |   46    |     67      |    fale     |
 4  |   46    |     34      |    fale     |
```

That is, I received a list of the subscribers of the user with ID 46 and found that I subscribed to users with IDs 71 and 53

Comment: *I get the result* The result structure do not match the query text...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test

```
SELECT F.USER_ID, 
       F.FOLLOWER_ID, 
       U.USERNAME, 
       U.NAME, 
       U.LAST_LOGIN, 
       F2.FOLLOWER_ID IS NOT NULL AS IS_FOLLOWER
FROM FOLLOWERS AS F
INNER JOIN USERS AS U ON (U.USER_ID = F.USER_ID)
LEFT JOIN FOLLOWERS AS F2 ON F.FOLLOWER_ID = F2.FOLLOWER_ID
                         AND F2.USER_ID = 89
WHERE F.USER_ID = '46'
```